# Highcharts 3 cannot render more than 1000 points in one series

Tags: highcharts

After upgrading for Highcharts 2.1.9 to 3.0.0 we found that it seems impossible to render more than 1000 points in one series.

If you add 1000 points to a series it renders ok.

If you add 1001 points to a series it does not render at all. If you interrogate the series afterwards the "data" array on the series is empty.

You can however render multiple series with 1000 points - so there does not seem to be a limitation in terms of the total number of points per chart.

Here is a jsFiddle which illustrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/YWVHx/47/

```
$(function () {

    var series1Data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        series1Data.push({
            x: (new Date()).getTime() + i * 10000,
            y: Math.random() * 100
        });
    }

    var series2Data = [];
        // If you change this back to 1000 the series gets rendered
        for (var i = 0; i < 1001; i++) { 
            series2Data.push({
                x: (new Date()).getTime() + i * 10000,
                y: Math.random() * 100 + 100
            });
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Foo'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
            text: null
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: '1000 Points - I work ;-)',
            data: series1Data
        }, {
            name: '1001 Points - I dont work :-(',
            data: series2Data
        }]
    });
});
```

Is this a limitation that was imposed on purpose or is it a problem with v3?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should set bigger turbothreshold:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Looks like you can have a problem with performance (rendering speed).

Comment: @SebastianBochan Why is the boost.js module a module and not built in to highcharts?

Comment: Because boost module does not support all functionalities like i.e markers etc. It is realted with the fact that in boost we do not generate SVG separate elements.

Answer (score 25):

For the other user's convenience , this is a complementary example that you can copy and paste:

```
        plotOptions:{
            series:{
                turboThreshold:5000//set it to a larger threshold, it is by default to 1000
            }
        }
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/YWVHx/339/ here for results

Comment: This helped alot to see where exactly it should be put !

Comment: Cool! You answer saved my day!