# Irregular time data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I encountered a problem when using **Irregular time data chart** in highcharts to draw a chart. problem as follows:

this is the series array:

```
series : [
{
 name:'test chart'
 data:[
            [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 0],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 4), 0.28],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.25] 
            ......
      ]
}
]
```

If the length of data array of a serie in series array is more than 1000,the chart won't be drawn ,and it shows blank ,but when the length of the data array is less than 1000,the chart shows normally.why? and how to fix it?is it a limitation of highchart for **Irregular time data chart**  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check turbo-threshold property if set ,Highcharts works well even for 1 million points. Share the fiddle with problem

Update : similar question answered already by Highchart Champ sebastian at  [Highcharts 3 cannot render more than 1000 points in one series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921399/highcharts-3-cannot-render-more-than-1000-points-in-one-series)

use : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

in your series

```
 series: [
               {
                type: 'scatter',
                name: 'some name',                                     
                data: something,
                turboThreshold: 7000,}
  ]
```

Comment: is turboThreshold setted in series？isn't it in plotOptions：series：turboThreshold？

Comment: The example link I shared with you, shown that you can keep it in plotOtions... however the code I written in above answer is from my highcharts graph where I used that in series and its works fine :)

Comment: turboThreshold is applicable at both the places plotOption and in series as well ..Please refer documentation of highcharts to clarify it. happy coding :)